# CodeIgniter 2.1.3 and mssql 2008 collation

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, collation

then problem I am having is that when I get data out of database everything is fine, but when I write data with special symbols to database I get special symbols coded.

ex. When I write **name (1.5), ie** I get the **name ( 1.5 & # 4 1 ; , ie** (without spaces). But when I get from database base everything is fine and **name (1.5), ie** is shown.

The problem is that my search with special symbols does not work.

here are the configurations.
database.config:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '10.87.4.147';
$db['default']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['default']['password'] = 'Q!w2e3r4';
$db['default']['database'] = 'rrr';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

as you've noticed my database collation is **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**.

I've tried setting values to:

```
$db[‘default’][‘char_set’] = ‘utf8’;
$db[‘default’][‘dbcollat’] = ‘utf8_general_ci’;
```

and:

```
$db[‘default’][‘char_set’] = ‘utf16’;
$db[‘default’][‘dbcollat’] = ‘utf16_general_ci’;
```

Any ideas how to write data with special symbols or have my search working. The search is simple, I get string, put it in SQL LIKE statement and return the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ever anyone will face the same problem, here is the solution:

I've used

```
 $newname = html_entity_decode($oldname);
```

And then inserted $newname. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter (2.1.3) doesn't handle character sets for the 'mssql' driver. You can set one like this:

```
@ini_set('mssql.charset', 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Thank you, where should I put this line?

Comment: As long as it is before the query containing special characters - it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you!!! It helped me a lot. You're a life saver.

However, it seem that only dots are working correctly. () are sttored as &#40; &#41;

Comment: This has nothing to do with character sets, see my reply on the CodeIgniter forums thread (and please pick just one place to ask questions :)).